# non conformable syntax in R

Tags: r

```
j <- c(-1.64,-0.27,0.18)
k <- matrix(c(51.43,13.425,12.015,13.425,12.94,8.69,12.015,8.69,9.1),3,3)
ellipse(j,k,alpha = .05,npoints = 250,newplot = TRUE, draw = TRUE)
```

Error in e1 %*% t(v1) : non-conformable argument

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you describe your goals.

Comment: `ellipse` is not a function in base R

Comment: I want to sketch an ellipse between health and education. That condition is shown by "j" data. "k" is matrix covariance. so what's the right syntax?

Comment: It looks like `ellipse` is a function from the package `mixtools`. It is very important that you specify the packages that you use when asking a question. The function draws a 2-dimensional ellipse, i.e., `j` must have length two and `k` must be a 2x2 matrix. You have a vector of length 3 and a 3x3 matrix, which is not what the function expects.

Comment: @Stibu oh okey. and then, if i want to make 3d ellipse, it can or not? i mean i have to change the function for it, or really can't with any function?

Comment: It doesn't look like this function could create a 3d ellipse (which would not be an ellipse at all but rather an ellipsoid...). There might be a function in some other package or you could create one yourself using a package for 3d graphics (for instance the `rgl` package).